# Are GeoTIFF larger than 4 GB automatically "BigTIFFs"

Tags: geotiff-tiff, bigtiff

I'm reading up on graphic formats and noticed that I have several GeoTIFFs that are larger than the apparent limit on TIFF file size of 4 GB. Can someone explain what I am missing here? Do BigTIFFs have a different file extension?

Comment: Probably best to read the original specification https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/bigtiff.html. The file extension is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tl;dr: Yes.

First of all, a file extension is a purely cosmetic thing.

You can rename a GeoTIFF file to `funny_cats.mpeg` and it would still be a GeoTIFF as the filename does not affect the actual bits and bytes of the file. The extension is just by convention. Some operating systems (like Windows) use it to decide which program should try loading a file but that's purely artificial.

TIFF files usually are named `.tif` or `.tiff`.

Secondly, BigTIFF is a special kind of a TIFF file. Meaning that the bits and bytes of the file are structured and ordered a bit different from a normal TIFF. BigTIFF exists because the original specification for TIFF files was limited to files of a maximum of about 4GB. The BigTIFF specification removes that limitation.

GeoTIFF is somewhat similar as it is also a standard based on the TIFF format. Some people might name their GeoTIFFs `.geotiff` but I have never seen that in the wild. They are usually called `.tif` as well.

There is no special extension for BigTIFF files. Programs and libraries decide how to handle a file's bits and bytes when loading. If your software is ancient, it might not be able to handle a BigTIFF TIFF file and crash.